# Creating elevation profile using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, elevation, road

[image]I have one road shapfile and one raster which has surface information

How can I combine them and create elevation profile?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the 3D Extension, then the [Stack Profile](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/stack-profile.htm) tool will create an elevation profile from a line. It doesn't "combine the lines and raster"

If you just want to get Z-values into the lines you can use the the [Interpolate Shape](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/interpolate-shape.htm) tool.

If you don't have access to the 3D extension, you'll need to break out the workflow, doing something like:

- Raster to Point (ensuring your take the elevation values into a field)
- You could then run [Feature Vertices to Points](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) (advanced license required) to turn the lines into points
- [Spatial Join](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) using the `closest` function to get the Z values onto your "line-points"
- At this point you'll need to either construct your lines from the points ([Points to Line](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/points-to-line.htm)) or use a [conflation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/an-overview-of-the-conflation-toolset.htm) technique.

Alternatively you could do this all in Python and an [InsertCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm), moving through the line geometry (vertices) using the [Get Cell Value](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-cell-value.htm) tool to pull the elevation from the raster at a given location.

Comment: Hi KHibma, I followed you advise to use Stack Profile. But I met a new problem,  the graph was a mess and FIRST_DIST can't contain all length, I put the screenshot in the original question, could you please see it?

Answer (score 0):

New in ArcGIS Pro 2.4 : 
Profile viewing it's fantastic for slicing a UAV derived SLPK mesh and compare to LiDAR from an earlier date as I have in example 2.

[image: Profile Viewing]

[ESRI Ireland and UK Whats New in ArcGIS 2.4](https://communityhub.esriuk.com/geoxchange/2019/6/28/whats-new-in-arcgis-pro-24)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Elevation tool for ArcGIS Pro available in the ArcGIS Marketplace. It is especially suited to compare profiles from different DEM, for example, to analyse the evolution of the elevation over time.
https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis-marketplace/listing/products/4c66005712cd4e9482b4a937dea86819